# Logon onto shared Windows account using individual passwords?

Tags: windows-xp, passwords, shared-access

In a networked Windows XP environment, I have a computer-controlled device which I want to connect to the network, but allow various people to use. The computer must be left running and logged on at all times.

My thought is to run the computer under a "shared account" which would allow each user to logon/unlock the screen using their own network password (I.e., the password for their personal account).

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Windows accounts can only have one password. They would have to use the same password for that "shared account", but otherwise it would work using the RDP.

If you want unique passwords, you might consider some VNC server as an alternative. Some of them might have multi-user support, but I'm not sure of this.